# submit without using id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wanna submit form to **reporturl.php** without using **id**.

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#name").val();
$.post("reporturl.php", {
url1: name,
}, function(data) {
alert(data);
$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});

});
});

</script>
```

Only the first one gets submitted and rest doesn't. Help me find a way so that all of it gets submitted on their respective clicks maybe using **$(this)** in **Jquery** code, but i am new to Jquery and don't know how to implement it

```
 <body>
<div>
<input id="name" value="first " type="hidden">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
<input id="name" value="second " type="hidden">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
<input id="name" value="third " type="hidden">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
<input id="name" value="fourth" type="hidden">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
<input id="name" value="fifth " type="hidden">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
<input id="name" value="sixth " type="hidden">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
<input id="name" value="seventh " type="hidden" >
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `id`'s have to be unique. You should use a classes instead.

Comment: What does the number of forms have to do with it? I don't see any forms in the html anyway. And without a class, you'd have to rely on the html structure to get the input that matches your button.

Comment: I thought you said you couldn't use a class. Saying it worked below, contradicts what you said here.

Comment: @jeroen Right ^^^ ?

Comment: You need to edit your question and the title. It contradicts what you accepted.

Comment: lol okay i am a liar @Fred-ii-

Comment: Come on, guys. Let's not fight now that everyone is on the same page.

Comment: Thanks, however @jeroen am sure would have submitted an answer yet he probably didn't know what to offer as a solution without a class. He knows his code pretty well ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm gone for a minute and see what happens! Not going to sue anybody just yet though :-)

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Nobody's "fighting" here *lol*, but just to "set the record straight". What the OP originally posted as a question as well as a comment, prevented one person from posting an answer, and probably others also ;-) The question was unclear from the beginning, *just saying*.

Comment: @jeroen Nah... plus, Bugs wouldn't take this to "the highest court" neither ;-) Enjoy your coffee.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How did you know ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I have my sources ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few changes:

1. Change all input `id` to `class`

   ```
   <div>
       <input class="name" value="first " type="hidden">
       <input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
   </div>
   <div>
       <input class="name" value="second " type="hidden">
       <input class="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
   </div>

   ...
   ```
2. Update your script accordingly

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {

       $(".submit").click(function() {  // listen to class, not id
           var name = $(this).prev().val(); // take the value from preceding input
           $.post("reporturl.php", {
               url1: name,
           }, function(data) {
               alert(data);
               $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
           });

       });

   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, It worked :)

Comment: Glad I helped! ))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve without change in your HTML you can do it as below snippet.

But duplication of ids in dom is not good practice at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).prev('input[type="hidden"]').val();
    alert(name);
    $.post("reporturl.php", {
      url1: name,
    }, function(data) {
      alert(data);      
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="name" value="first " type="hidden">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="name" value="second " type="hidden">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="name" value="third " type="hidden">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="name" value="fourth" type="hidden">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="name" value="fifth " type="hidden">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="name" value="sixth " type="hidden">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="name" value="seventh " type="hidden" >
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
```